# API to to find y co-ordinate/intercept of a given point on a Path

Tags: android, charts, android-custom-view

I am building an [inverted axes line chart](https://www.google.com/search?q=Inverted%20Line%20Chart&client=ubuntu&hs=Ae0&channel=fs&biw=1920&bih=1053&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0CAcQ_AUoAWoVChMIoMn479zqxgIVkxGSCh1OrQym#channel=fs&tbm=isch&q=Inverted%20axes%20%20Line%20Chart).To the draw the lines of the chart  I am using android [Path](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path.html) apis.Now when the user touches any point on the graph,I would like to show the corresponding data value.I know the x coordinate but I want to find corresponding y coordinate.Using the y coordinate I want to show the corresponding data value.

Has anybody come across simple APIs to do it..something like path.getYCoordinate()..I know I can store all the lines and check whether the point lies in which line.Then using the slope of line find corresponding Y-coordinate.

Comment: THat's not really part of the path API, because a Path isn't generally in 1 direction-  it can have multiple Y values per x.  Or a bitmap in the middle there.  A path totally works for drawing a graph, but it isn't limited to that, so it doesn't have graph-like functionality built in.  Its more like a series of draw commands to be performed later.

Comment: @GabeSechan yup thats true ...just wanted to check whether people have found easier way to do it since there are lot of graph libraries written in android